# Given $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x-1}$, I need to find $f(2x-3)$

Tags: functions

I'm not clear how to proceed:

Given $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{x-1}$, I need to determine what $f(2x-3)$ is equal to.

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: What are you supposed to do with those functions? Also: please tell us what you have tried

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{x^2}{x-1}$ or $\frac{x^2}{x} -1$? I assume the former but you wrote the latter.

Comment: Is the question to write an expression for $f(2x-3)$ given the formula for $f(x)$?

Comment: I edited this to format better - let me know if it is wrong

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{x-1}$, we want to find $f(2x-3)$.

To do so, we substitute $2x-3$ every place we see an x in $f(x),$ and simplify:

$$f(2x-3) = \dfrac{(2x -3)^2}{(2x-3)-1}= \dfrac{4x^2 - 12x + 9}{2x-4}$$

Comment: that's it I was looking for. Thx. First time I am here and I do not know much English... and mathematics :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

$$f(2x - 3) = \frac{(2x-3)^2}{(2x-3) - 1} = \frac{(2x-3)^2}{2x-4}$$